# How to Switch between writing to file and printing in C

Tags: c, linux, system

### Description

I am trying to make a basic application in C which works in the terminal.
My goal is to write a code that prints some outputs in file with dup2(foo, STDOUT_FILENO);
some outputs to the terminal. The problem is ı couldn't understand how can switch between two of them.
I read several questions but ıcouldnt understand.

### Bug/ problems

When I write in C

```
  int foo = open("./foo.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  dup2(foo, STDOUT_FILENO);
  sytem("man man"); //trying yo write man in foo.txt
  some_macig_function();
  printf("welcome back to terminal output");
```

I don't know what is the that some macig_fonciton my code continue the write to a file even if my child process is done(I guess) and second and last problem is my foo.txt is wrong there are outputs like (MMAANNUUAALL SSEECCTTIIOONNSS)

Comment: You really need to do error-checking in your code. Never assume that a call to `open` will succeed, for example.

Comment: I am pretty new at linux and c how can ı do that

Comment: @KamilCuk I am printing man man output in foo.txt not to console but after that point, my code does write file and shell.  My txt becomes man man out outs with some duplicated characters and welcome back to terminal output . and I see welcome back to terminal in terminal agin

Comment: @KamilCuk `man` seems capable of detecting if it's being run in a tty or a pipe, try `man man | cat -`. I guess the OP is hitting that case

Comment: @alagner `man -P cat man` should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can switch between two

Use a temprary file descriptor to store stdout.

In bash you could practice it:

```
exec {tempfd}<&1       # copy stdout to temporary fd
exec 1>./foo.txt       # redirect to file
man man
exec 1>&${tempfd}      # restore stdout
echo welcome back to terminal output
```

Similar in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int tempfd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);      // exec {tempfd}<&1
    int filefd = open("./foo.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
    dup2(filefd, STDOUT_FILENO);             // exec 1>./foo.txt
    system("echo man man");
    dup2(tempfd, STDOUT_FILENO);          // exec 1>&${tempfd}
    printf("welcome back to terminal output\n");

    system("echo ---- THIS IS IN foo.txt file: ---");
    system("cat foo.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

[outputs on repl](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/VibrantUnnaturalCrash#main.c):

```
welcome back to terminal output
---- THIS IS IN foo.txt file: ---
man man
```

> last problem is my foo.txt is wrong there are outputs like (MMAANNUUAALL SSEECCTTIIOONNSS)

[Redirecting man page output to file results in double letters in words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634497/redirecting-man-page-output-to-file-results-in-double-letters-in-words)

> I am pretty new to both c

Compile with all possible warnings `-Wall -Wextra`. Check your programs with sanitizer `-fsanitize=address` and with `valgrind` for correctness.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I still prints file and terminal @KamilCuk

Comment: `I still prints file and terminal` well, I do not understand. Please try to be specific. What does print where? Does the output is printed to both the file and the terminal? Is the `man man` output printed to both file and terminal? Is the `welcome back` message printed to both file and terminal? If so - your question misses an [MCVE] - if so, please post full _minimal_ program with all relevant `#include` and `main` needed to have the same behavior.

Comment: İt still prints "welcome back to terminal output" to file and terminal other parts are correct the only difference with your response is I use print instead of puts deu to check childs id is this the reason  @KamilCuk

Comment: Sure, there's a typo. `dup2` args are in wrong order!

Comment: I'm using printf sorry is this the typo

Comment: `puts("sutff")` is exactly equivalent to `printf("stuff\n")`. Stdout is line buffered in interactive programs - to see the output, it's good to add a newline, to make sure it's really flushed.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly only anomaly is when I write man KamillCuk prints awesome :)