# How to properly use dvioptions in preview functon from sympy?

Tags: python, latex, sympy, miktex

Form [preview](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.preview.preview) documentation,

> If the value of ‘output’ is different from ‘dvi’ then command line options can be set (‘dvioptions’ argument) for the execution of the ‘dvi’+output conversion tool. These options have to be in the form of a list of strings (see subprocess.Popen).

I couldn't manage to find any doc regarding valid arguments of `dvioptions` except some examples like this.

```py
from sympy import preview

preview(r'$$H_{2}O$$', viewer='file', filename='water.png', euler=False, dvioptions=["-T", "tight", "-z", "0", "--truecolor", "-D 600", "-bg", "Transparent"])
```

what do these `"-z", "0", "--truecolor"` mean? or, better, if you could just point me to appropriate doc.

Comment: Looks like the options of `dvipng`. Type `man dvipng` on the command line for a full list

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Got my [answer](https://www.nongnu.org/dvipng/dvipng_4.html#Command_002dline-options)! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look like the command line options of `dvipng`. You can see a full list if you run `man dvipng`:

```
DVIPNG(1)            User commands               DVIPNG(1)



NAME
       dvipng - A DVI-to-PNG translator

SYNOPSIS
       dvipng [options] filename

       dvipng [options] [filename] -

DESCRIPTION
       This program makes PNG and/or GIF graphics from DVI files as obtained
       from TeX and its relatives.

       If GIF support is enabled, GIF output is chosen by using the dvigif
       binary or with the --gif option.

       The benefits of dvipng/dvigif include

       o   Speed. It is a very fast bitmap-rendering code for DVI files, which
       makes it suitable for generating large amounts of images on-the-
       fly, as needed in preview-latex, WeBWorK and others.

       o   It does not read the postamble, so it can be started before TeX
       finishes. There is a --follow switch that makes dvipng wait at end-
       of-file for further output, unless it finds the POST marker that
       indicates the end of the DVI.

       o   Interactive query of options. dvipng can read options interactively
       through stdin, and all options are usable. It is even possible to
       change the input file through this interface.

       o   Supports PK, VF, PostScript Type1, and TrueType fonts, subfonts
       (i.e., as used in CJK-LaTeX), color specials, and inclusion of
       PostScript, PNG, JPEG or GIF images.

       o   and more...

OPTIONS
       Many of the parameterless options listed here can be turned off by
       suffixing the option with a zero (0); for instance, to turn off page
       reversal, use -r0.  Such options are marked with a trailing *.

       -   Read additional options from standard input after processing the
       command line.

       --help
       Print a usage message and exit.

       --version
       Print the version number and exit.

       -bd num
       -bd color_spec
       -bd 'num color_spec'
       Set the pixel width of the transparent border (default 0). Using
       this option will make the image edges transparent, but it only
       affects pixels with the background color. Giving a color_spec will
       set the fallback color, to be used in viewers that cannot handle
       transparency (the default is the background color). The color spec
       should be in TeX color \special syntax, e.g., 'rgb 1.0 0.0 0.0'.
       Setting the fallback color makes the default border width 1 px.

       --bdpi num
       This option only has an effect when using bitmapped (PK) fonts. The
       option sets the base (Metafont) resolution, both horizontal and
       vertical, to num dpi (dots per inch). This option is necessary when
       manually selecting Metafont mode with the --mode option (see
       below).

       -bg color_spec
       Choose background color for the images. This option will be ignored
       if there is a background color \special in the DVI. The color spec
       should be in TeX color \special syntax, e.g., 'rgb 1.0 0.0 0.0'.
       You can also specify 'Transparent' or 'transparent' which will give
       you a transparent background with the normal background as a
       fallback color. A capitalized 'Transparent' will give a full-alpha
       transparency, while an all-lowercase 'transparent' will give a
       simple fully transparent background with non-transparent
       antialiased pixels. The latter would be suitable for viewers who
       cannot cope with a true alpha channel.  GIF images do not support
       full alpha transparency, so in case of GIF output, both variants
       will use the latter behaviour.

       -d num
       Set the debug flags, showing what dvipng (thinks it) is doing. This
       will work unless dvipng has been compiled without the "DEBUG"
       option (not recommended). Set the flags as you need them, use -d -1
       as the first option for maximum output.

       -D num
       Set the output resolution, both horizontal and vertical, to num dpi
       (dots per inch).

       One may want to adjust this to fit a certain text font size (e.g.,
       on a web page), and for a text font height of font_px pixels (in
       Mozilla) the correct formula is

           <dpi> = <font_px> * 72.27 / 10 [px * TeXpt/in / TeXpt]

       The last division by ten is due to the standard font height 10pt in
       your document, if you use 12pt, divide by 12. Unfortunately, some
       proprietary browsers have font height in pt (points), not pixels.
       You have to rescale that to pixels, using the screen resolution
       (default is usually 96 dpi) which means the formula is

           <font_px> = <font_pt> * 96 / 72 [pt * px/in / (pt/in)]

       On some high-res screens, the value is instead 120 dpi. Good luck!

       --depth*
       Report the depth of the image. This only works reliably when the
       LaTeX style preview.sty from preview-latex is used with the active
       option. It reports the number of pixels from the bottom of the
       image to the baseline of the image. This can be used for vertical
       positioning of the image in, e.g., web documents, where one would
       use (Cascading StyleSheets 1)

           <IMG SRC="<filename.png>" STYLE="vertical-align: -<depth>px">

       The depth is a negative offset in this case, so the minus sign is
       necessary, and the unit is pixels (px).

       --dvinum*
       Set this option to make the output page number be the TeX page
       numbers rather than the physical page number. See the -o switch.

       -fg color_spec
       Choose foreground color for the images. This option will be ignored
       if there is a foreground color \special in the DVI. The color spec
       should be in TeX color \special syntax, e.g., 'rgb 1.0 0.0 0.0'.

       --follow*
       Wait for data at end-of-file. One of the benefits of dvipng is that
       it does not read the postamble, so it can be started before TeX
       finishes. This switch makes dvipng wait at end-of-file for further
       output, unless it finds the POST marker that indicates the end of
       the DVI. This is similar to tail -f but for DVI-to-PNG conversion.

       --freetype*
       Enable/disable FreeType font rendering (default on). This option is
       available if the FreeType2 font library was present at compilation
       time.  If this is the case, dvipng will have direct support for
       PostScript Type1 and TrueType fonts internally, rather than using
       gsftopk for rendering the fonts. If you have PostScript versions of
       Computer Modern installed, there will be no need to generate
       bitmapped (PK) variants on disk of these. Then, you can render
       images at different (and unusual) resolutions without cluttering
       the disk with lots of bitmapped fonts.  One reason to disable
       FreeType font rendering would be to generate identical output on
       different platforms, since FreeType uses the native renderer and
       therefore can give slightly different output on each platform.

       --gamma num
       Control the interpolation of colors in the greyscale anti-aliasing
       color palette.  Default value is 1.0.  For 0 < num < 1, the fonts
       will be lighter (more like the background), and for num > 1, the
       fonts will be darker (more like the foreground).

       --gif*
       The images are output in the GIF format, if GIF support is enabled.
       This is the default for the dvigif binary, which only will be
       available when GIF support is enabled. GIF images are palette
       images (see the --palette option) and does not support true alpha
       channels (see the --bg option). See also the --png option.

       --height*
       Report the height of the image. This only works reliably when the
       LaTeX style preview.sty from preview-latex is used with the active
       option. It reports the number of pixels from the top of the image
       to the baseline of the image. The total height of the image is
       obtained as the sum of the values reported from --height and
       --depth.

       -l [=]num
       The last page printed will be the first one numbered num. Default
       is the last page in the document.  If num is prefixed by an equals
       sign, then it (and the argument to the -p option, if specified) is
       treated as a physical (absolute) page number, rather than a value
       to compare with the TeX \count0 values stored in the DVI file.
       Thus, using -l =9 will end with the ninth page of the document, no
       matter what the pages are actually numbered.

       --mode mode
       This option only has an effect when using bitmapped (PK) fonts. Use
       mode as the Metafont device name for the PK fonts (both for path
       searching and font generation). This needs to be augmented with the
       base device resolution, given with the --bdpi option. See the file
       <ftp://ftp.tug.org/tex/modes.mf> for a list of resolutions and mode
       names for most devices.

       -M* This option only has an effect when using bitmapped (PK) fonts. It
       turns off automatic PK font generation (mktexpk).

       --nogs*
       This switch prohibits the internal call to GhostScript for
       displaying PostScript specials. --nogs0 turns the call back on.

       --nogssafer*
       Normally, if GhostScript is used to render PostScript specials, the
       GhostScript interpreter is run with the option -dSAFER. The
       --nogssafer option runs GhostScript without -dSAFER. The -dSAFER
       option in Ghostscript disables PostScript operators such as
       deletefile, to prevent possibly malicious PostScript programs from
       having any effect.

       --norawps*
       Some packages generate raw PostScript specials, even non-rendering
       such specials.  This switch turns off the internal call to
       GhostScript intended to display these raw PostScript specials.
       --norawps0 turns the call back on.

       -o name
       Send output to the file name. A single occurrence of %d or %01d,
       ..., %09d will be exchanged for the physical page number (this can
       be changed, see the --dvinum switch). The default output filename
       is file%d.png where the input DVI file was file.dvi.

       -O x-offset,y-offset
       Move the origin by x-offset,y-offset, a comma-separated pair of
       dimensions such as .1in,-.3cm.  The origin of the page is shifted
       from the default position (of one inch down, one inch to the right
       from the upper left corner of the paper) by this amount.

       -p [=]num
       The first page printed will be the first one numbered num. Default
       is the first page in the document.  If num is prefixed by an equals
       sign, then it (and the argument to the -l option, if specified) is
       treated as a physical (absolute) page number, rather than a value
       to compare with the TeX \count0 values stored in the DVI file.
       Thus, using -p =3 will start with the third page of the document,
       no matter what the pages are actually numbered.

       --palette*
       When an external image is included, dvipng will automatically
       switch to truecolor mode, to avoid unnecessary delay and quality
       reduction, and enable the EPS translator to draw on a transparent
       background and outside of the boundingbox. This switch will force
       palette (256-color) output and make dvipng revert to opaque clipped
       image inclusion. This will also override the --truecolor switch if
       present.

       --picky*
       No images are output when a warning occurs. Normally, dvipng will
       output an image in spite of a warning, but there may be something
       missing in this image. One reason to use this option would be if
       you have a more complete but slower fallback converter. Mainly,
       this is useful for failed figure inclusion and unknown \special
       occurrences, but warnings will also occur for missing or unknown
       color specs and missing PK fonts.

       --png*
       The images are output in the PNG format. This is the default for
       the dvipng binary. See also the --gif option.

       -pp firstpage-lastpage
       Print pages firstpage through lastpage; but not quite equivalent to
       -p firstpage -l lastpage. For example, when rendering a book, there
       may be several instances of a page in the DVI file (one in
       "\frontmatter", one in "\mainmatter", and one in "\backmatter"). In
       case of several pages matching, -pp firstpage-lastpage will render
       all pages that matches the specified range, while -p firstpage -l
       lastpage will render the pages from the first occurrence of
       firstpage to the first occurrence of lastpage.  This is the
       (undocumented) behaviour of dvips. In dvipng you can give both
       kinds of options, in which case you get all pages that matches the
       range in -pp between the pages from -p to -l. Also multiple -pp
       options accumulate, unlike -p and -l.  The - separator can also be
       :. Note that -pp -1 will be interpreted as "all pages up to and
       including 1", if you want a page numbered -1 (only the table of
       contents, say) put -pp -1--1, or more readable, -pp -1:-1.

       -q* Run quietly.  Don't chatter about pages converted, etc. to standard
       output; report no warnings (only errors) to standard error.

       -Q num
       Set the quality to num. That is, choose the number of antialiasing
       levels for bitmapped fonts (PK), to be num*num+1. The default value
       is 4 which gives 17 levels of antialiasing for antialiased fonts
       from these two. If FreeType is available, its rendering is
       unaffected by this option.

       -r* Toggle output of pages in reverse/forward order. By default, the
       first page in the DVI is output first.

       --strict*
       The program exits when a warning occurs. Normally, dvipng will
       output an image in spite of a warning, but there may be something
       missing in this image. One reason to use this option would be if
       you have a more complete but slower fallback converter. See the
       --picky option above for a list of when warnings occur.

       -T image_size
       Set the image size to image_size which can be either of bbox,
       tight, or a comma-separated pair of dimensions hsize,vsize such as
       .1in,.3cm. The default is bbox which produces a PNG that includes
       all ink put on the page and in addition the DVI origin, located 1in
       from the top and 1in from the left edge of the paper. This usually
       gives whitespace above and to the left in the produced image. The
       value tight will make dvipng only include all ink put on the page,
       producing neat images.

       --truecolor*
       This will make dvipng generate truecolor output. Note that
       truecolor output is automatic if you include an external image in
       your DVI, e.g., via a PostScript special (i.e., the graphics or
       graphicx package). This switch is overridden by the --palette
       switch.

       -v* Enable verbose operation. This will currently indicate what fonts
       is used, in addition to the usual output.

       --width*
       Report the width of the image. See also --height and --depth.

       -x num
       This option is deprecated; it should not be used. It is much better
       to select the output resolution directly with the -D option. This
       option sets the magnification ratio to num/1000 and overrides the
       magnification specified in the DVI file.  Must be between 10 and
       100000.  It is recommended that you use standard magstep values
       (1095, 1200, 1440, 1728, 2074, 2488, 2986, and so on) to help
       reduce the total number of PK files generated.  num may be a real
       number, not an integer, for increased precision.

       -z num
       Set the PNG compression level to num. This option is enabled if
       your libgd is new enough. The default compression level is 1, which
       selects maximum speed at the price of slightly larger PNGs. For an
       older libgd, the hard-soldered value 5 is used. The include file
       png.h says "Currently, valid values range from 0 - 9, corresponding
       directly to the zlib compression levels 0 - 9 (0 - no compression,
       9 - "maximal" compression). Note that tests have shown that zlib
       compression levels 3-6 usually perform as well as level 9 for PNG
       images, and do considerably fewer calculations. In the future,
       these values may not correspond directly to the zlib compression
       levels."

NOTES
       The full manual is accessible in info format, on most systems by typing

           info dvipng

COPYRIGHT
       This program is released under the GNU Lesser General Public License
       version 3, see the COPYING file in the dvipng distribution or
       <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.

       Copyright (c) 2002-2015, 2019 Jan-AAke Larsson



dvipng (TeX Live) 1.17        2021-02-26                 DVIPNG(1)
```

Comment: There seems to be issue with formatting as letters are repeated. Could you fix it so that I can mark this as accepted answer

Comment: @ShihabusSakibRad That's just the syntax of the man page for bold parts. If you don't like it, you can remove it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634497/redirecting-man-page-output-to-file-results-in-double-letters-in-words

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that. Anyway , I've marked this as accepted answer